# Собрал ПК, вечные синие экраны (bsod) с разными ошибками. В чём проблема?

Tags: windows, железо, bsod

Собрал новый пк, вот характеристики:
Материнская плата: gigabyte b450m ds3h v2 (rev. 1.0)
Видеокарта: Palit GeForce RTX 3060 Ti
Процессор: ryzen 5 3600
Оперативная память: Kingston FURY Beast 2x16GB DDR4 PC4-25600
SSD: Crucial BX500 1TB
Первый bsod был примерно через 2 часа после сборки. Я сидел в дискорде и момент вылета произошёл когда я решил посмотреть характеристики монитора. Этому bsod я не принял особого значения. На след. день у менябыло синих экранов раз 20, не меньше, с разными ошибками. Иногда вылетает экран сразу после включения. Вот список ошибок, которые я встречал:
UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
REGISTRY_ERROR
APC_INDEX_MISMATCH
KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
ATTEMMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY
KERNEL_AUTO_BOOST_INVALID_LOCK_RELEASE
Это только те, что я успел заснять.
Что вызвало проблему показало только 2 раза. Это были aswsnx.sys (аваст) и ntfs.sys. Однако при помощи bluescreenviev узнал, что в каждом bsod ошибку также вызывал ntoskrnl.exe. Я проверил оперативку, ssd, sata-кабели, разные драйвера устанавливал. Ничего не помогает. Винду устанавливал с оф сайта (с VPNом), некоторые драйвера при помощи sdi, некоторые из оф.приложениий. Синий экран может появиться просто так сам, но чаще всего вылетает когда я запускаю много приложений в песочнице avast. Ищу причину уже 3ий день. Помогите
P.S. конфигурация ПК не очень, т.к. собирался для узконаправленной деятельности

Comment: Ничего не разгоняли - процессор, память? Память тестировали вдолгую - разными режимами заполнения?

Comment: Соглашусь с @CrazyElf по поводу тестов памяти. Ещё бы проверил на перегрев, в т.ч. чипсета материнской платы. Ну, и стандартный вопрос: видеокарта в майнинге не была?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Да, температуры везде где можно помониторить - хорошая идея

Comment: `некоторые драйвера при помощи sdi, некоторые из оф.приложениий` мне вот это понравилось. Тебя самого точно ничего в этой фразе не смущает?